# How to add a card view effect for a linear layout

Tags: android, cardview

How to add a card view effect for a linear layout

**I have a card View**

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                       xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/eventListRootId"
            card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/dimen_card_elevation"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/dimen_card_CornerRadius"
            card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
            style="@style/style_card_view">

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**How to achieve the same effect in list view, is it possible using selectors**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Wrap your `LinearLayout` with a `CardView`.

Comment: Yes, you can achieve it but what you in `LinearLayout`? @Devrath

Answer (score 1):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rel1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"


    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:transitionName="open_mediaplayer"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="3dp"

    >

   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

you can add listview inside linear layout to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Just use `CardView` theme as your `LinearLayout` style. In case of wanting some changes, just create a new theme and extend it from `CardView` theme.